# Transpile and Compilation using Angular-CLI

Tags: compilation, angular5, angular-cli, transpiler

I'm reading the book Angular 5 Projects and have come across this sentence:

```
The Angular CLI uses Webpack to transpile, compile, and deploy project code.
```

Transpile and compilation are given in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752815/transpilation-process-in-angular-2)

The transpile is from TypeScript to JavaScript.

What language does angular-cli compile the JavaScript code to? And is angular-cli doing both: transpile and compilation?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The CLI doesn't compile the Typescript code to any other language than JavaScript. The "compile" that your book may be referring to are the steps where the CLI uglifies, minifies and bundles the JS for eventual deployment. This may be a better question for the author rather than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript must be `transpiled` into JavaScript using the `tsc compiler`, which requires some configuration.

Yes, it's doing both. When working in Angular you will using TypeScript to code in files designated as `your-component.ts` with the 'ts' signifying that it's a TypeScript file. Angular then takes these files and does the transpiling (conversion to another language). In this case that would be TypeScript to Javascript. Once this is done Angular uses these now created JavaScript files to communicate to the browser with.